# A $3$-$4$-$5$ right $\triangle ABC$ ($AC=5$) fits in a square such that $A$ is also vertex of the square. Find the side of square.

Tags: geometry, triangles

> A right angle triangle ABC of sides $3$, $4$, and $5$ ($AC=5$) is fit in a square such that $A$ is also vertex of square . Find the side of square.

Some error is occurring while uploading picture. If you have some problem understanding ask me in comments.

My attempt:

I tried to use Pythagoras by assuming side $x$. But I think I am missing something. There should be an easy way to finish it.[image]

\color{red}{ Is this square unique ?}

Comment: I don't think we can help you without the image.

Comment: Huh?  So $A$ is the vertex of a square a million miles long.... There's nowhere near enough information.

Comment: I try uploading again

Comment: I suppose an interesting question what is the smallest possible side and can it be smaller than $4$.  Are the points B and C both contained on sides of the square?

Comment: @fleeblood Yes . That's what I meant by fit.

Comment: "But I think I am missing something. There should be an easy way to finish it."  That's not "easy"?  I don't see why you think there'd be an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Establish the ratio below from the two similar right triangles with 3 and 4 as hypotenuses,

$$\frac ax=\frac{a-x}{\frac34 x}$$

Use $x=\sqrt{16-a^2}$ to get the equation
$\sqrt{16-a^2}=\frac14a$, which yields

$$a=\frac{16}{\sqrt{17}}$$

Comment: You may want to explain how you got the third side broken into $\frac 34 x$ and $a-\frac 34 x$  by (I presume) similarity of the two triangles with hypotenuse $3$ and $4$ and complimentary angles.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is a vertex of the square; and $B$ in on a side of the square not adjacent to $A$; and $C$ is on the other side not adjacent to $A$.

And if the side of the square in $s$ we can, using cartesian coordinates, assume $A$ is at $(0,0)$ and $B$ is at $(s,y)$ and $C$ is at $(x, s)$.

Then we have $s^2 + y^2 = 4^2$ and $x^2 + s^2 = 5^2$ and $(s-x)^2+(y-s)^2 = 3$

Solve for $s$. (If possible)

If $s > 4$ then that isn't the best fitting.  The best fitting is that $AB$ is the side of the $4\times 4$ square.

Comment: It is exactly what I did . But there may be easy way . Or is there a way to check if this is unique case or not ?

Comment: I got $$s={16 \over \sqrt{17}}$$

Comment: If you got a unique solution then this is the only way to do it.  However that is a solution for $B$ on side $2$ and $C$ on side $3$.  If we put $B$ on side $1$ and $C$ on side $2$ we get side is $4$ and $B$ is on the vertex.  The other options; $B$ on side $1,2,3,4$ and $C$ on side $1,2,3,4$ will all yield no solutions except $(B,C)$ on sides $(2,3)$ (which both yield $s=16/\sqrt{17}$ and $B$ an adjacent vertex to $A$ (which both yield $s=4$).

Comment: It is a relatively easy system to simplify, since you get $y$ in terms of $s$ from the first equations and $x$ in terms of $s$ from the second.  So the last equation is just $(s-\sqrt{25-s^2})^2+(s-\sqrt{16-s^2})^2=9$.  W|A says that the two solutions are $\frac{16}{\sqrt{17}}$ and $\frac{16}{\sqrt{65}}$.  The second is invalid but the first works out (checked by GeoGebra).

Comment: "But there may be easy way ."  Why isn't this easy enough for you?